# Does the book "JSF 2.0, the complete reference" by Ed Burns draw a good comparison between 1.2 and 2.0?

Tags: reference, comparison, jsf-2

I'm about to analyse and present the improvements of JSF 2.0 (in comparison to JSF 1.2).
Now I'm looking for a good book for that.

My first guess would be the reference by Ed Burns, but the readers' reviews start to unsettle me: http://www.amazon.com/JavaServer-Faces-2-0-Complete-Reference/product-reviews/0071625097/ref=cm_cr_dp_hist_5?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=0&filterBy=addFiveStar

Will this book be helpful for my task? I'm already familiar with JSF 1.2, so an pure update backed by additional information would be great.

Additionally I found this German book, which in contrast has much better reviews: Do any of the German readers recommend it?
http://www.amazon.de/JavaServer-Faces-2-0-Grundlagen-erweiterte/dp/3898646068/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top

TIA,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I own both books and have read the 1.2 version more than once (since I used to create and correct exams for students based on this book).

I got the 2.0 version a while back. If you want a book that focusses completely on the differences between 1.2 and 2.0, this might not be the very best book although in all fairness Ed Burns does make some attempt.

In the introduction there's a 3 page overview of things that are new in JSF 2.0 and throughout the book there are various sections labeled "JSF 2.0 Tip" which makes it clear that something is new to JSF 2.0.

In comparison, I also own Bill Burke's book about EJB: `Enterprise JavaBeans 3.0`, of which I recently bought the latest version `Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1`. In this book there is almost no reference at all to things that are specifically new in EJB 3.1. `JSF 2.0 the complete reference` absolutely does better here.

To sum up, for what you want the book is 'average'. Not super good, but also not super bad.

*<sub>(for learning about JSF in general I think the book is really good though, there just should have been a version for people already very familiar with JSF 1.2)</sub>*